# How to split Alphanumeric with Symbol in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I want to spilt Alphanumeric with two part Alpha and numeric with special character like `-`

```
string mystring = "1- Any Thing"
```

I want to store like:

```
numberPart = 1 

alphaPart = Any Thing
```

For this i am using Regex

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"([a-zA-Z]+)(\d+)");
            Match result = re.Match("1- Any Thing");

            string alphaPart = result.Groups[1].Value;
            string numberPart = result.Groups[2].Value;
```

If there is no space in between string its working fine but space and symbol both alphaPart and numberPart showing `null` where i am doing wrong Might be Regex expression is wrong for this type of filter please suggest me on same

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
(\d+)(?:[^\w]+)?([a-zA-Z\s]+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/41oJ27/2)

**Explanation:**

- `(\d+)` - capture one or more digit
- `[^\w]+` match anything except alphabets
- `?` this tell that anything between word and number can appear or not(when not space is between them)
- `[a-zA-Z\s]+` match alphabets(even if between them have spaces)

Answer (score 1):

Start of string is matched with `^`.

Digits are matched with `\d+`.

Any non-alphanumeric characters are matched with `[\W_]` or `\W`.

Anything is matched with `.*`.

Use

```
(?s)^(\d+)\W*(.*)
```

See [proof](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fs%29%5E%28%5Cd%2B%29%5CW*%28.*%29&i=1-%20Any%0D%0A%20Thing)

`(?s)` makes `.` match linebreaks. So, it literally matches everything.